# Oracle SQL to find sum of difference of date by Group

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am trying to find a total duration consume by a Group by calculating date difference in a following query

```
with event AS (
SELECT 9000 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03-01 09:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS 
TIMESTAMP, 'Start' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9000 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03/10 10:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS 
TIMESTAMP, 'END' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9001 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03-10 11:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS 
TIMESTAMP, 'Start' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9001 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03/20 10:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS 
TIMESTAMP, 'END' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9000 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03-20 10:05:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS 
TIMESTAMP, 'Start' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9000 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03/25 09:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS 
TIMESTAMP, 'END' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9001 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03-25 10:15:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS 
TIMESTAMP, 'Start' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9001 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03/26 12:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS 
TIMESTAMP, 'END' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9002 AS ID, TO_DATE('2017-03-26 14:30:27','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS 
TIMESTAMP, 'Start' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9002 AS ID, TO_DATE('2017-04-05 15:02:56','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS 
TIMESTAMP, 'END' AS EVENT FROM DUAL
)
select id, min(timestamp) as call_start_ts, max(timestamp) as call_end_ts,
   max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) as duration
from event t
group by id
order by 1;
```

I have also configure the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73f48/2/0)

Please help me

**EDIT**

Expected Result will be like below

[image]

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Nishant currently I am getting the duration for Group "9000" 24 days but it must be "15" days what is happening the query is taking maximum end (25-03-2018) and substracting from 01-03-2018) but I want sum of (first end - start) + second(end - start)

Comment: You have a `DATE` data type in a column called `TIMESTAMP`; what is your intended data type?

Comment: my intended Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LAG` or `LEAD` analytic functions to get the next `END` event's time:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7855c/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE event ( id, timestamp, event ) AS
  SELECT 9000, TO_DATE('2018-03-01 09:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9000, TO_DATE('2018-03/10 10:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'END'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9001, TO_DATE('2018-03-10 11:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9001, TO_DATE('2018-03/20 10:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'END'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9000, TO_DATE('2018-03-20 10:05:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9000, TO_DATE('2018-03/25 09:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'END'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9001, TO_DATE('2018-03-25 10:15:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9001, TO_DATE('2018-03/26 12:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'END'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9002, TO_DATE('2017-03-26 14:30:27','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9002, TO_DATE('2017-04-05 15:02:56','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'END'   FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id,
       MIN( timestamp ) AS start_ts,
       MAX( end_time  ) AS end_ts,
       SUM( end_time - timestamp ) AS duration
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         timestamp,
         event,
         LEAD( CASE event WHEN 'END' THEN timestamp END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp ) AS end_time
  FROM   event
)
WHERE  event = 'Start'
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7855c/4/0)**:

```
|   ID |             START_TS |               END_TS |           DURATION |
|------|----------------------|----------------------|--------------------|
| 9000 | 2018-03-01T09:00:00Z | 2018-03-25T09:00:00Z | 13.996527777777779 |
| 9001 | 2018-03-10T11:00:00Z | 2018-03-26T12:00:00Z |           11.03125 |
| 9002 | 2017-03-26T14:30:27Z | 2017-04-05T15:02:56Z |  10.02255787037037 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your problem:

```
WITH event AS (
SELECT 9000 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03-01 09:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP, 'Start' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9000 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03/10 10:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP, 'END' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9001 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03-10 11:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP, 'Start' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9001 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03/20 10:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP, 'END' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9000 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03-20 10:05:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP, 'Start' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9000 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03/25 09:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP, 'END' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9001 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03-25 10:15:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP, 'Start' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9001 AS ID, TO_DATE('2018-03/26 12:00:00','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP, 'END' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9002 AS ID, TO_DATE('2017-03-26 14:30:27','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP, 'Start' AS EVENT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9002 AS ID, TO_DATE('2017-04-05 15:02:56','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP, 'END' AS EVENT FROM DUAL
)
,rn_event AS 
(
  select event.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY ID ORDER BY TimeSTAMP) AS rn from event
)
, diff_event AS 
(
SELECT e.ID, f.TIMESTAMP AS Start_time, e.timestamp AS End_Time, e.TIMESTAMP - f.timestamp AS duration
FROM rn_event e
INNER JOIN rn_event f 
ON f.id = e.id AND f.EVENT = 'Start' AND f.rn = e.rn - 1
)
SELECT ID,MIN(Start_Time) START_TS, MAX(END_TIME) END_TS, ROUND(SUM(Duration)) AS Duration
FROM diff_event
GROUP BY ID;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ID      START_TS                END_TS                 DURATION
9000    2018-03-01T09:00:00Z    2018-03-25T09:00:00Z    14
9001    2018-03-10T11:00:00Z    2018-03-26T12:00:00Z    11
9002    2017-03-26T14:30:27Z    2017-04-05T15:02:56Z    10
```

A demo for the above query:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73f48/87

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in two steps. First i match records in the same interval then i sum up their duration.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73f48/83

```
   SELECT
    Id,
    round(SUM(duration))
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t.id,
            MIN (t2. TIMESTAMP) - t. TIMESTAMP AS duration
        FROM
            event t,
            event t2
        WHERE
            t.Id = t2.Id
        AND t2.Event = 'END'
        AND t.Event = 'Start'
        AND t2. TIMESTAMP > t. TIMESTAMP
        GROUP BY
            t. TIMESTAMP,
            t.Id
    )
GROUP BY
    Id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
id, round(sum(end_timestamp - start_timestamp),3) DURATION
from (
select 
       t.id, 
       t.timestamp START_TIMESTAMP,
       case when LEAD(t.event,1) OVER (partition by id order by timestamp, event desc) = 'END' 
            then LEAD(t.timestamp,1) OVER (partition by id order by timestamp, event desc)
       else null end as END_TIMESTAMP
from event t
)tt
where end_timestamp is not null
group by id
```